# How to get PrestaShop employee language ID

Tags: get, prestashop

How to get PrestaShop employee id lang? With default language I know:

```
    $defaultLanguage = intval(Configuration::get('PS_LANG_DEFAULT'));
    $languages = Language::getLanguages();
    $iso = Language::getIsoById($defaultLanguage);
```

But how to get employee lang?

I tried this:

```
    $cookie = new Cookie('ps');
    $defaultLanguage = $cookie->id_lang;
    $languages = Language::getLanguages();
    $iso = Language::getIsoById((int)($defaultLanguage));`
```

But it does not work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get it within an AdminController child objects:

```
$this->context->employee->id_lang
```

Comment: Nope, some case, you can not get employee obj.